# Parallel independent rest calls in Play Async action

Tags: java, playframework, completable-future

I Would like to make 3 independent parallel rest call in a Java play Async action and return a CompletionStage which renders a view with all results of the rest calls.

I am able to accomplish this in Scala using for Comprehension

```
def index() = Action.async { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    val f1 = getRecommendations()
    val f2 = getViewedItems()
    cal f2 = getCustomer()
    val futureResults = for {
      recommendations <- f1
      viewedItems <- f2
      customer <- f3
    } yield (recommendations, viewedItems, customer)
    futureResults.map(results => Ok(views.html.readingList.render(results._1, results._2, result_3))
    )
  }
```

I would like to do something similar in Java Play Async action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got some time to work on this. The closest I have got in Java is the following:

```
    public CompletionStage<Result> index() {
    CompletableFuture<List<Item>> recommendationsCF = getRecommendations();
    CompletableFuture<List<Item>> viewedItemsCF = getViewedItems();
    CompletableFuture<List<Customer>> customerCF = getCustomer();   

  return  CompletableFuture.allOf(recommendationsCF,viewedItemsCF,customerCF).thenApply((voidcf) -> ok(
            views.html.home.render(
                    recommendationsCF.join(),
                    viewedItemsCF.join(),
                    customerCF.join())
    ));
```